# A CV-qualified type cannot be converted to the cv-unqualified type

Tags: c++

I've written the example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A(const A&){ std::cout << "A(const A&)" << std::endl; }
    A(){ std::cout << "A()" << std::endl; }
};

struct B
{
    B(){ std::cout << "B()" << std::endl; }
    operator A(){ std::cout << "operator A()" << std::endl; return A(); }
};

B b;

void foo(A) { }

int main(){ std::cout << "main function starting..." << std::endl; foo(b); }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f3dc20acbbd5704)**

It works fine, but if we replace `B b;` with `const B b;` it won't work.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A(const A&){ std::cout << "A(const A&)" << std::endl; }
    A(){ std::cout << "A()" << std::endl; }
};

struct B
{
    B(){ std::cout << "B()" << std::endl; }
    operator A(){ std::cout << "operator A()" << std::endl; return A(); }
};

const B b;

void foo(A) { }

int main(){ std::cout << "main function starting..." << std::endl; foo(b); }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc9483315228fbb9)**

Although the Standard says in the section `13.3.3.1/6 [over.best.ics]`:

> Any difference in top-level cv-qualification is subsumed by the
>   initialization itself and does not constitute a conversion.

I wish someone to explain me why the seond example doesn't work.

Comment: In the second example, surely `operator A(){` needs to be `operator A() const {`?

Answer (score 0):

The line you quoted is under the section titled **13.3.3.1.1 Standard Conversion Sequences**. The conversion from `B` to `A` is a user defined conversion. The rules for user defined conversions are under the next section of the standard and is titled **13.3.3.1.2 User-defined conversion sequences**

What you quoted does not apply to user defined conversions.